# PHP - dropdown populates but will not select using 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, selected

I've been working on this for at least a month, and can't find this question elsewhere. I know I'm just missing something stupid, but...

There are 2 tables: biz and bizclass. bizclass.bizclassName holds the 250+ classifications to populate the dropdown box. Population from bizclass table and update to biz table both work, but when I try to select the current data from biz.bizClass1 , the dropdown initial value is set as the null value "Select Class". Please help. It's driving me bonkers. I'm too old for many more sleepless nights! Newbie - somewhat familiar with php and javascript but don't have a grip on ajax yet.

```
echo "Class1: <select name ='bizClass1' id='bizClass1'/> ";

$sql = 'SELECT bizclassName FROM bizclass ORDER BY bizclassName';
$query2 = 'SELECT `bizClass1` FROM `biz` WHERE `bizID` = "'. $search .'"'; 
$clist = mysqli_query($connection,$sql); 
$num=mysqli_num_rows($clist);
$olist = mysqli_query($connection, $query2); // select  bizClass from biz 

$bizTblRecord = mysqli_fetch_assoc($clist); // option values from bizclass table to populate the dropdown
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($olist); // fetched the bizClass from biz

if ($row2['bizClass1'] == $bizTblRecord['bizclassName']){
    printf ("<option value='%s' selected >%s</option> ", $row2['bizClass1'], $row2['bizClass1']);
} else {
    printf ("<option value=''>Select Class</option> ");
}//end if


for($numrows=1; $numrows<= $num; $numrows++)
{
    // Associative array
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($clist);

    printf ("<option value='%s'>%s</option>",$row['bizclassName'],$row['bizclassName']);

} //end for

echo "</select>";

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($clist); 
mysqli_free_result($olist);
```

Comment: why don't you re-factor the code to separate the concerns. Separate database calls from presentation logic. It may help to shed some light on the issue.

Comment: You fetch a row each from your two queries and compare them. Sinceyou're getting the "select class" option, obviously your two rows AREN'T the same and have different values.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, I will see if I can wrap my head around that. Marc, the biz table was updated from the dropdown, so I expected them to be equal. I tested one bizID multiple times trying to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    echo "Class1: <select name ='bizClass1' id='bizClass1'/>
                         <option value=''>Select Class</option> ";

    $sql = 'SELECT bizclassName FROM bizclass ORDER BY bizclassName';
    $clist = mysqli_query($connection,$sql); 
    $num=mysqli_num_rows($clist);



    $querySEARCH = 'SELECT `bizClass1` FROM `biz` WHERE `bizID` = "'. $search .'"'; 
    $SEARCHlist = mysqli_query($connection, $querySEARCH); // select  bizClass from biz 
    $rowSEARCH= mysqli_fetch_assoc($SEARCHlist); // fetched the bizClass from biz

    for($numrows=1; $numrows<= $num; $numrows++)
    {
        // Associative array
        $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($clist);

        if ($rowSEARCH['bizClass1'] == $row['bizclassName']){
            printf ("<option value='%s' selected >%s</option> ", $rowSEARCH['bizClass1'], $rowSEARCH['bizClass1']);
        } else {
            printf ("<option value='%s'>%s</option>",$row['bizclassName'],$row['bizclassName']);
        }//end if

    } //end for

    echo "</select>";

    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($clist); 
    mysqli_free_result($SEARCHlist);
```

If statement have to be inside the loop to compare each option with search.

Test tables:

biz

```
bizID   bizClass1
1       ronaldo
2       shevshenko
3       falcao
4       zidane
5       valderrama
```

bizclass

```
bizclassName
falcao
ozil
ronaldo
messi
shevshenko
valderrama
hazard
totti
```

Comment: chofer, I'm learning (or trying to), and I don't understand what the [0] in ($row2[0]['bizClass1'] refers to. Does that indicate the index of the first returned item?

Comment: I do appreciate your help, but this didn't work for me. Replaced both the if and for statements. I'm working from a 10 year old php/mysql textbook, and it's been about 7 years since I've done any real coding. Thought about enum (to keep just one table), but I have 4 fields for classifications and I feel the separate table is the better option since I never know when I may have to update the classifications. Don't know if it matters, but my son helped me with this - he says the original version works on PC, but my mac just won't cooperate.

Comment: -->[test](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tj1-ty7)<-- I made a test for you, hope it'll be useful.   try it and tell me what happens, or perhaps make a [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org) maybe it'll be easier to find the error. For mysql , on top right TOOLS-> mysql

Comment: chofer, by the time I got there, the page said"account suspended". I've managed a hack that works but not nicely. I added text boxes to call the saved value so I can view what is there. I just have to re-enter the dropdown content before I can save... a little nuisance, but i'm getting pretty pressed for  a deadline. I do appreciate your help!

Comment: Look for the answer edit, I made two tables and i did some edits to your code and it works. The thing is that if stament have to be inside the loop to compare each option otherwise only compare first option of $clist

Comment: AWESOME!! chofer, you are a godsend.... thank you so much! Sorry it took so long for me to reply--(was called away for family issues). I hope some day I can help someone as much as you have helped me.

Comment: So I understand my error - the code$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($clist); needs to be inside the for loop

Comment: the value you want to selected have to be inside the loop to compare with each option, otherwise if only compare the first option. Great that it works, you can help somebody and search for more help here in StackOverflow.
I'm glad to help you and good luck!!
PD: Sorry for my english, I'm learning :)